# Trying to export MySQL query as CSV using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm getting a warning

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array
>   given

when trying to export a MySQL query result as CSV using PHP code like this:

```
public static function exportLocationCSV($id){
        $sql =<<<EOF
            SELECT col1, col2, col3
            FROM table1
            JOIN table2 ON table1.col0=table2.col0 
            WHERE table1.col0 = $id;
EOF;


        // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

        // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        // output the column headings
        fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

        $query_export= self::$db_connection->query($sql);
        $rows = array();
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_export)){
            $rows[] = $r;
        }

        // loop over the rows, outputting them
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
}
```

Comment: What does `self::$db_connection->query()` function look like? Is it a custom function that you created ?

Comment: You might also want to try `var_dump($query_export)` to see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` API's. `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will not work with the `mysqli_` API. Your second while loop is the one using the wrong function call.

This line:

```
// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

should be change to the correct function call:

```
// loop over the rows, outputting them
foreach($rows AS $row) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

Comment: It says `WARNING: mysqli_fetch_assoc expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array is given`

Comment: Because you're not using a query resource for your second loop (you're using an array) you do not need to use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` at all.  You should likely use a `foreach()` loop there @plzhelp Apologies for not noticing that earlier.

Answer (score -1):

mysql_fetch_assoc used to fetch a result row as an associative array [here is more about mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

what you are trying to do is to pass `$rows` which is array while `mysql_fetch_assoc` expecting you to pass `mysql_query`